# how to create table with colored cells based on coordinates with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

(the points object can not be changed)

How to create?:
table with 30 rows and 30 cols;
all cells have blue background;
all cells that exist in points object with coordinates (x=cols, y=rows) to have red background.

For example:
cell on row 15 and col 12 must be with red background.
cell on row 18 and col 12 must be with red background.
cell on row 21 and col 12 must be with red background.
and so on.

```
var Points = {
    "points" : [
        { "id": "F2", "x": "12", "y": "15" },
        { "id": "F3", "x": "12", "y": "18" },
        { "id": "F4", "x": "12", "y": "21" },
        { "id": "F5", "x": "12", "y": "25" },
        { "id": "F6", "x": "12", "y": "27" },
        { "id": "F7", "x": "12", "y": "29" },
        { "id": "C1", "x": "30", "y": "12" },
        { "id": "C2", "x": "30", "y": "15" },
        { "id": "C3", "x": "30", "y": "18" },
        { "id": "C4", "x": "30", "y": "25" },
        { "id": "C5", "x": "30", "y": "27" },
        { "id": "C6", "x": "30", "y": "29" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Seems pretty straight-forward, where are you running into trouble?

Comment: Do you know how to make a table? Do you know how to use eq()?

Comment: I can create table and append rows and so on. I don't know how to create the red cells based on coordinates in the points object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is to "walk" through all elements from points array and then, using `eq()` from jquery you can do your stuff. Remember that in html `<tr>` means row (line) and `<td>` is the column. You can check the stuff in this [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/stefanz/2xntR/)